# I'm attempting to build a Jquery Image carousel that changes the content of a seperate div on the page.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been messing around with a ton of different attempts none of which have proved even remotely successful. If someone is willing to, would you either walk me through or point me in the right direction.

I'm using http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/ Jcarousel as the image carousel on the top of the page with 3 images up at a time.

I'm looking for something like this following link http://tamarackcellars.com/ but where the content at the bottom of the page changes instead of the whole page loading to a new page when you click on one of the wines.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you tried. Add your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831808/trying-to-update-the-content-of-the-content-div-of-a-page-by-clicking-a-linked

This is some of the code from my previous attempts. The code was cleaned up to not include the customers information and content because they didn't want it posted yet.

Comment: I'm going to include the original code, understand that page1 2 and 3 all exist and are in the correct locations in regard to the src tags. The image files also exist and the jcarousel is behaving as intended with the exception of the content div not being replaced with the loaded page per the load function

http://jsfiddle.net/x57LP/

This is the actual code copied and pasted. I reference jquery.js and jquery.hcarousel.min.js and both of those are loaded correctly on the server and accesible.

Answer (score 0):

ok I am assuming you can get the carousel plugin to work, if not let me know.

If I understand you right, you want the content of the page to change but not to redirect. If this is static content then what you want is relatively simple and can be solved many ways.

First set up your carousel and give each image or content the same class like class="carouselObj". Then create a container on the same page that will hold different information with respect to each element of the carousel.

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="info">1st image info</div>
   <div class="info">2nd image info</div>
   <div class="info">3rd image info</div>
   <div class="info">4th image info</div>
</div>
```

Now to add some jquery to make it functional.The idea here is that when one of the images changes via click or from a timed event, the corrosponing information in the container will also change. Here is some code to give you the idea.

```
$('.carouselObj').click(function(){
var index = $('.carouselObj').index(this); // gets the index of carousell image clicked
$('.info').eq(index).show().siblings('.info').hide(); // shows the corrosponding element and hides the others.
});
```

Now in the css file you need to make sure you originally set the first info class

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. I'm doing three images up at a time with carousel (no problems with carousel) and that when you click on one image the page loads a php page

Comment: Your method would work if the content I'm trying to load was completely static, but I'm loading things based off of the users selection combined with data about the user that I already have. The javascript (jquery) will be calling a php page generated by python

Comment: I don't get what your having trouble with. Can you just modify the pages content? If you were to send what item you selected via the index way above through an ajax call to the php page and then update the same page based on the php response, would that work?

Comment: I'm calling the page (in the example page1.html because i didnt write the php pages yet) on click, or at least I think I am already. in http://jsfiddle.net/x57LP/ I call the click event with the following

$(function()
{
    $('#mycarousel ul li a').click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));          
    });
});
 which should call the content div to load with the html pages.

Comment: Do you have a website up or are you running local on lamp or something similar?

Comment: I have it on an apache server I run for testing

Comment: I'm trying a new method for calling the ajax call based off of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923683/link-in-one-div-trying-to-load-content-in-a-seperate-div?rq=1 Made some progress, now the other pages are being loaded but the return false (also tried e.preventDefault with the e in the function) is not stopping the page from navigating forward to the link.

Also thank you all for the help.

Comment: Cam you post the relevant code so I can take a look? preventdefualt will work if used properly an look for small errors.

Comment: well it wont work on fiddle well with an ajax call. Either way I got it to at least stop from directing. Consider checking your local path to jquery. I use googles cached version [link](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery) Also your classes are mismatched it should be link and not navlink. When i changed those things preventdefualt kept me on the page.

Comment: I updated the class to be "link" on both, must have had a typo because it wasn't that way on my local file. Additionally I updated the source to the google cached version in http://jsfiddle.net/x57LP/6/ and it still tried to connect to the page (which obviously doesn't exist). I tested with your two changes on fiddle and still it tries to load the other page in instead of loading it within the div. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Here is an uploaded functional version of the page with the issue that when you click the image they take you to the page they are linked to instead of loading it in the div below inovino.syntheticzero.com/winepage.html (the images are just from else where on the web and are not properly attributed or licensed, just for mock up purposes)

Comment: this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x57LP/8/) works when you separate your files like your supposed to when you use fiddle for easy manipulation. IDk maybe you need to wrap your javascrpit in an onload function.

Comment: if your using chrome or firefox try using the web dev tools. Press f12 and right click the navlink and select inspect element. Then look on the right hand side and locate the eventlistners tab. When I do that on your site it shows no event listeners. That means the javascript/jquery is not targeting your class "navlink".

Comment: try loading your javascript from an external file. I think that will help. Sometimes jquery gets buggy from local javascript.

Comment: I'll work through this tomorrow. Thanks again. Hopefully I can get this working.